# How do I return the sum of values from a file?

Tags: python-3.x, file

I am trying to convert a string of plus and minus signs from a file to +1 and -1 respectively, and then print the resulting sum of all of the plus and minus 1's.

Here is my attempt at the problem:
[Problem statement and attempted code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Iqa.png)

I think the issue is in my return statements, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mcve], and fully explain what needs to be modified. Do not post pictures of code - [edit] your question and copy/paste your code inside, formatting it by selecting it and hitting CTRL+C

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score -1):

You are returning the first operator you come across before iterating through all of them.
You should remove both the return statements inside the for loop i.e

```
return num_plus
return num_minus
```